# How to recreate this logical argument(syllogism) using logical operators and any statements and data-types in C#

Tags: c#, logical-operators

1. This cake is either vanilla or chocolate.

This cake is not chocolate.
Therefore, this cake is vanilla.

2. All men are mortal

Socrates is a man.
Therefore, Socrates is mortal.

This is the logical argument - how to recreate these using operators in C#?

Comment: Is this some kind of assignment?

Comment: Could you describe your question more clearly

Comment: C# is a programming language, not a formalism for mathematics. You can express something that resembles such a line of reasoning, but C# has no native, obvious way of expressing a predicate like "this X has property P or property Q but not both", let alone apply reasoning steps on it to transform it into another predicate. It's not Prolog. (Of course you can implement Prolog in C#, much as you can implement any programming language in any other, but that's not typically useful.)

Comment: The second _could_ be expressed through the class `Man` having a readonly bool property `IsMortal` which resolves to `true` and `Socrates` being an instance of said class ... but I am not sure how that fits into your context (which we know nothing about).

Comment: @Fildor yes it is

Comment: I'm a newbie who is learning c# on pirple.com but I'm not able to complete this H.W.

Comment: OK, so I guess this is _not_ about artificial intelligence. You are just supposed to express the quoted syllogisms specifically in C# Code ... right?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try of what I *think* is asked in this assignment:

### First example

```
1. This cake is either vanilla or chocolate.
2. This cake is not chocolate. 
=> Therefore, this cake is vanilla.
```

```
class Cake{

    public Cake(bool isChocolate){
        this.IsChocolate = isChocolate;
    }

    public bool IsChocolate {get; private set;} = false;
    public bool IsVanilla => !IsChocolate; // "Not IsChocolate" == opposite of IsChocolate
}

// ...
public static void Main()
{
    var cake = new Cake(false);
    if( cake.IsChocolate ) Console.WriteLine("This cake is Chocolate!");
    else Console.WriteLine("This cake is Vanilla!"); // No further check: If it's not choc, 
                                                     // it must be vanilla.
}
```

Or maybe through Interface:

```
public interface ICake{
   // Cake Properties
}

public class Chocolate : ICake{} // Chocolate is-a Cake

public class Vanilla : ICake{} // Vanilla is-a Cake

// ...

public static void Main(){
    ICake cake = new Vanilla();
    if( cake is Chocolate chocoCake )
    {
         Console.WriteLine("It's chocolate!");
    }
    else // Not chocolate => must be vanilla
    {
         Console.WriteLine("It's vanilla!");
    }
}


/* Attention:
 * This will of course break your logic, if you added 
 * class Strawberry: ICake{}
 */
```

or

```
public enum CakeType{
   Chocolate,
   Vanilla
}

class Cake{
    public CakeType TypeACake {get; private set;} = CakeType.Vanilla;
}

// ...

public static void Main(){
   var thisCake = new Cake();
   Console.WriteLine($"This cake is {(cake.TypeACake == CakeType.Chocolate ? "": "not ")}Chocolate.");
   Console.WriteLine($"Therefore it is {(cake.TypeACake == CakeType.Vanilla ? "": "not ")}Vanilla.");
}
```

There are tons of variations of this, actually. Depends on how it is supposed to be used. So, imho not really great of an assignment - although this could be exactly the goal of the lesson rather than having you find a "correct implementation".

### Second example

```
1. All men are mortal
2. Socrates is a man. 
=> Therefore, Socrates is mortal.
```

```
class Man {
    public bool IsMortal => true;
}

// ...

public static void Main(){
  Man Socrates = new Man();
  
  Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Socrates)} is a '{nameof(Man)}', therefore he is {(Socrates.IsMortal?"mortal":"immortal")}.");
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/J3xzwx

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           bool VanillaCakeIS = true;
            bool ChocolateCakeIS =false ;
            if ( VanillaCakeIS || !ChocolateCakeIS)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This Cake is vanilla");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("This Cake is chocolate");}
            
            bool MenAreMortal = true;
            bool SocratesIsMan = true;
            if (MenAreMortal && SocratesIsMan)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("socrates is mortal");  
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("socrates is not mortal"); }
        }
    }
}
```